# Neo4j how to make a relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 nodes with a property name A and B. Each one have multiple phone contacts saved.

- User A have user C in his contacts
- User B have user C in his contacts

  [image: contacts]

How to connect user C with a relation that he `KNOWS` user A and B?

First thing I must merge user C, than make a relation named `KNOWS`.

Comment: Hi @Chadi if one of the answers has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> How to connect user C with a relation that he KNOWS user A and B?

Simply do:

```
MATCH(a {name:"A"}) // Match nodes with property name = "A" and store it in a variable
MATCH(b {name:"B"}) // Match nodes with property name = "B" and store it in b variable
MERGE (c {name:"C"}) // merge c (will be created if a node with name = "C does not exists yet")
CREATE UNIQUE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(a) // Will create :KNOWS relationship from c to a if it not exists
CREATE UNIQUE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(b) // Will create :KNOWS relationship from c to b if it not exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MERGE to create both C and the KNOWS relation in one step:

```
MATCH (a:user {name:'A'}) MERGE (c:user {name:'C'})-[:KNOWS]->(a);
```

Here you are looking for a *:user* node with property *name*='A'.  If this is found, the result is passed to the MERGE clause.  You are giving MERGE a complete *path*; MERGE will create the parts of the path that do not exist.  In this case, it will create a node of type *:user* and give it a *name* property set to 'C'; it will also create a :KNOWS relation from C to A.  MERGE will use the existing node *a* it has been given.  In this way, MERGE is different from CREATE, because CREATE would try to create everything, including a new node a.

If you had other properties to set on your node C you could set those properties at the same time using the ON CREATE sub-clause:

```
MATCH (a:user {name:'A'}) MERGE (c:user {name:'C'})-[:KNOWS]->(a) ON CREATE SET c={name:'C', phone:'+1 234 5678'};
```